# Unwanted Duplicate Posts Showing in Pagination Pages

Tags: posts, pagination

For some reason, I have posts that keep repeating on certain pagination pages using the code below. It's completely random, so I have no idea how to fix the problem. Maybe it's something in the post itself that's causing it to be repeated?

Some examples of the problem can be found here:

- https://www.suddenlysenior.com/page/64/
- https://www.suddenlysenior.com/page/65/
- https://www.suddenlysenior.com/page/66/
- https://www.suddenlysenior.com/page/67/
- https://www.suddenlysenior.com/page/68/

```
<?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>   

<div class="blogcontent"> 
    <div class="post_img"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <?php $img = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ); ?>
    <?php $image_alt = get_post_meta( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true); ?>
                <?php if($img) { ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo $img; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image_alt; ?>">
                <?php } ?></a></div>
    <div class="post_content">
    <?php 
        $category_detail=get_the_category($post->ID);//
            foreach($category_detail as $cd){ ?>

                <a href="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>/category/<?php echo $cd->slug; ?>/"><span class="boldtag"><?php echo $cd->cat_name; ?></span></a>
        <?php       }
    ?>

        <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h1>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        <ul class="author clearfix">
            <li>By <em><?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></em> <span>· <?php the_time('M d, Y') ?></span></li>
            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">MORE...</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<div class="paginationsec">
    <?php // Previous/next page navigation.
        the_posts_pagination( array(
            'prev_text'          => __( '<i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i> Prev', 'twentyfifteen' ),
            'next_text'          => __( 'Next <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>', 'twentyfifteen' ),
            'before_page_number' => '<span class="meta-nav screen-reader-text">' . __( '', 'twentyfifteen' ) . ' </span>',
        ) ); ?>

</div>

<?php else: endif; ?>
```

Comment: No need to use "if(have_posts()) "

Comment: Did you try disabling all plugins to see if the problem persists? When did you start noticing the duplicate posts?

Comment: It's persisted before plugins were even installed. The original developer couldn't figure it out either.

Comment: If you run a WP_Query() and print its results, do you get duplicate posts?

Comment: No idea..I'm not a WP developer, so I have no clue how to do that.

Comment: Add this before the code you shared, it will print some formatted text with the posts data. Check it to see if posts are duplicated. `echo '<pre>';
            print_r((new WP_Query(array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'posts_per_page' => 50,            
            )))->posts);
            echo '</pre>';`

Comment: I figured it out and posted all posts on one page. There are no duplicates, so that means some of my posts aren't showing. https://www.suddenlysenior.com/list-all-posts/

Comment: Something must be screwed up with the pagination...I'm able to print all of the posts on a single page.

Comment: I figured out what's causing the problem, I just don't understand why. I have a bunch of old posts that were published on the exact date and time on March 26, 2018. When I change the publish date for posts that repeat, it no longer repeats it in the navigation. Why would a post published date-timestamp cause it to repeat in navigation????

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107005/discussion-between-himad-and-jpollar).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with a custom WP_Query to rule out any possible code messing up with your main query pagination. Like this:

```
<?php
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'paged'=> $paged) );

?>
<?php while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>   

<div class="blogcontent"> 
    <div class="post_img"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <?php $img = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ); ?>
    <?php $image_alt = get_post_meta( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true); ?>
                <?php if($img) { ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo $img; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image_alt; ?>">
                <?php } ?></a></div>
    <div class="post_content">
    <?php 
        $category_detail=get_the_category($post->ID);//
            foreach($category_detail as $cd){ ?>

                <a href="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>/category/<?php echo $cd->slug; ?>/"><span class="boldtag"><?php echo $cd->cat_name; ?></span></a>
        <?php       }
    ?>

        <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h1>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        <ul class="author clearfix">
            <li>By <em><?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></em> <span>· <?php the_time('M d, Y') ?></span></li>
            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">MORE...</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<div class="paginationsec">
  <nav class="navigation pagination show">
    <div class="nav-links">
    <?php 
        echo paginate_links( array(
            'base'         => str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 999999999 ) ) ),
            'total'        => $query->max_num_pages,
            'current'      => $paged,
            'format'       => '?page=%#%',
            'show_all'     => false,
            'type'         => 'plain',
            'end_size'     => 5,
            'mid_size'     => 1,
            'prev_next'    => true,
            'prev_text'    =>__( '<i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i> Prev', 'twentyfifteen' ),
            'next_text'    => __( 'Next <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>', 'twentyfifteen' ),
            'before_page_number' => '<span class="meta-nav screen-reader-text">' . __( '', 'twentyfifteen' ) . ' </span>',
            'add_args'     => false,
            'add_fragment' => '',
        ) );
    ?>
    </div>
  </nav>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!!! I appreciate your time and effort!